# Assigning back 'sa_role'

Tags: sybase, role

We are upgrading Sybase 12 to Sybase 15.7. The sysroles of 12.5 does not migrate well because of conflicts in the role id in Sybase15. So we were advised to remove the sysroles and recreate it based on syssrvroles. During this process, we somehow lost the 'sa_role' for user:sa to our application database.

How do we assign the role back, as none of the users have sa_role privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sp_role "grant","sa_role", sa
```